# BinaryCrossentropy() only predicts positive or negative on my data, not able to get all fp, tp, fn, tn to calculate precision

Tags: image, binary, classification, precision, prediction

I have list of images with binary classification labels, I'm using BinaryCrossentropy() from Keras.metrics to train a network for detecting positive cases which are rare (6%), following a tutorial from Tensorflow on anomaly detection:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data#look_at_the_data_distribution
I'm using the same activation function 'sigmoid' and same approach, but I can't get pos/neg classification, my model only predicts negatives or positives during training (negatives if I use 'sigmoid' activation, positives if I use 'softmax' activation)

```
# Set parameters
INPUT_DIM = 224
WIDTH = 224
HEIGHT = 672
DEPTH = 1
BATCH_SIZE = 32
NUM_EPOCHS = 100
STEP_PER_EPOCH = 2
N_CLASSES = 1

# Command line arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--directory", required=True, help="path to input directory")
ap.add_argument("-t", "--target", required=True, help="name of the target field")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# Info file
label_file = pd.read_csv('/Users/ebrahamalskaf/Documents/Labels.csv')

# Loading images and labels
(images, labels) = utils.load_label_png(args["directory"], label_file, args["target"], INPUT_DIM)
images = images // 255.0

# Splitting data
(X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid) = train_test_split(images, labels, train_size=0.7, stratify=labels)
print(y_train[:32])
print(y_valid[:32])

# Initialise the optimiser and model
print("[INFO] compiling model ...")
Opt = Adam(lr=0.001)
Loss = BinaryCrossentropy()
METRICS = [
    tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives(name='tp'),
    tf.keras.metrics.FalsePositives(name='fp'),
    tf.keras.metrics.TrueNegatives(name='tn'),
    tf.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives(name='fn'),
    tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
    tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
    tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall'),
    tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'),
    tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='prc', curve='PR'),  # precision-recall curve
]

def build_model(output_bias=None):
    if output_bias is not None:
        output_bias = tf.keras.initializers.Constant(output_bias)
    model = Sequential()
    inputShape = (HEIGHT, WIDTH, DEPTH)

    # if we are using "channels first", update the input shape
    if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
        inputShape = (DEPTH, HEIGHT, WIDTH)

    # first set of CONV => RELU => POOL layers
    model.add(Conv2D(20, (5, 5), padding="same",
                     input_shape=inputShape))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

    # second set of CONV => RELU => POOL layers
    model.add(Conv2D(50, (5, 5), padding="same"))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

    # first (and only) set of FC => RELU layers
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(20, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0001)))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))

    # softmax classifier
    model.add(Dense(N_CLASSES, activation='sigmoid', bias_initializer=output_bias))

    # Tune the learning rate for the optimizer
    model.compile(optimizer=Opt,
                  loss=Loss,
                  metrics=METRICS)

    return model

weigth_path = "{}_my_model.best.hdf5".format("image_mortality_LeNet")
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(weigth_path, monitor='val_prc', save_best_only=True, mode='max', save_weights_only=False)

early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_prc',
    verbose=1,
    patience=10,
    mode='max',
    restore_best_weights=True)

# Initial bias
image_model = build_model()
initial_bias = np.log([0.053])
model = build_model(output_bias=initial_bias)
initial_weights = os.path.join(tempfile.mkdtemp(), 'initial_weights')
model.save_weights(initial_weights)

# Reload model with initial bias
image_model = build_model()
image_model.load_weights(initial_weights)

# Tensorboard logs
logdir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir, histogram_freq=1)

# Training the model
# print("[INFO] Training the model ...")
history = image_model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid),
                          epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                          callbacks=[early_stopping, checkpoint, tensorboard_callback])

# summarize history for loss
plt.plot(history.history['precision'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_precision'])
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('Mortality CNN training')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train accuracy', 'validation accuracy', 'train loss', 'validation loss'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

# Saving model data
model_json = image_model.to_json()
with open("image_mortality_LeNet.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)

K.clear_session()


## HERE IS MY IMAGE LOADING FUNCTION##

def load_label_png(directory, target, df_info, im_size):
    """
    Read through .png images in sub-folders, read through label .csv file and
    annotate
    Args:
     directory: path to the data directory
     df_info: .csv file containing the label information
     im_size: target image size
    Return:
        resized images with their labels
    """
    # Initiate lists of images and labels
    images = []
    labels = []

    # Loop over folders and files
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory, topdown=True):

        # Collect perfusion .png images
        if len(files) > 1:
            folder = os.path.split(root)[1]
            folder_strip = folder.rstrip('_')
            dir_name = int(folder_strip)
            dir_path = os.path.join(directory, folder)

            for file in files:
                if '.DS_Store' in files:
                    files.remove('.DS_Store')

                # Loading images
                file_name = os.path.basename(file)[0]
                if file_name == 'b':
                    img1 = mpimg.imread(os.path.join(dir_path, file))
                    img1 = resize(img1, (im_size, im_size))
                elif file_name == 'm':
                    img2 = mpimg.imread(os.path.join(dir_path, file))
                    img2 = resize(img2, (im_size, im_size))
                elif file_name == 'a':
                    img3 = mpimg.imread(os.path.join(dir_path, file))
                    img3 = resize(img3, (im_size, im_size))

                    out = cv2.vconcat([img1, img2, img3])
                    gray = cv2.cvtColor(out, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                    out = gray[..., np.newaxis]
                    
                    patient_info = df[df["ID"].values == int(folder_strip)]
                    the_class = patient_info[target]

                    images.append(out)
                    labels.append(the_class)

    return (np.array(images), np.array(labels))
```

HERE IS A SNIPPET OF MY TRAINING LOGS

Epoch 1/100
33/33 [==============================] - 71s 2s/step - loss: 0.2875 - tp: 0.0000e+00 - fp: 0.0000e+00 - tn: 1987.0000 - fn: 113.0000 - accuracy: 0.9462 - precision: 0.0000e+00 - recall: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.4866 - prc: 0.0524 - val_loss: 0.2839 - val_tp: 0.0000e+00 - val_fp: 0.0000e+00 - val_tn: 852.0000 - val_fn: 48.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.9467 - val_precision: 0.0000e+00 - val_recall: 0.0000e+00 - val_auc: 0.5000 - val_prc: 0.0533

I tried to concatenate or stack my labels in one array, this didn't work, then I tried to convert the training and validation labels into lists, then back to NumPy arrays, interestingly, by doing so I got some tp and fp values in the first epoch, then none from the second epoch onwards, only tn and fn

Comment: After changing my image loading function to make images a column in the data frame containing the labels, then creating 2d NumPy array from the images using: X_train = np.array([np.array(x) for x in df_train['images']]), and taking the labels out of the data frame: y_train = np.array(df_train.pop(args["target"]))                                                        I managed to get all tp, fp, tn, fn in the first epoch, but not been able to get them on the validation set or from 2nd epoch onwards. I will be grateful for any comments.

Comment: example: Epoch 2/100
5/5 [==============================] - 80s 15s/step - loss: 0.6947 - tp: 26.0000 - fp: 486.0000 - tn: 1501.0000 - fn: 87.0000 - accuracy: 0.7271 - precision: 0.0508 - recall: 0.2301 - auc: 0.5073 - prc: 0.0538 - val_loss: 0.7022 - val_tp: 0.0000e+00 - val_fp: 0.0000e+00 - val_tn: 852.0000 - val_fn: 48.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.9467 - val_precision: 0.0000e+00 - val_recall: 0.0000e+00 - val_auc: 0.5000 - val_prc: 0.0533

Comment: example: Epoch 3/100
5/5 [==============================] - 78s 15s/step - loss: 0.7026 - tp: 0.0000e+00 - fp: 0.0000e+00 - tn: 1987.0000 - fn: 113.0000 - accuracy: 0.9462 - precision: 0.0000e+00 - recall: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.5000 - prc: 0.0538 - val_loss: 0.7032 - val_tp: 0.0000e+00 - val_fp: 0.0000e+00 - val_tn: 852.0000 - val_fn: 48.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.9467 - val_precision: 0.0000e+00 - val_recall: 0.0000e+00 - val_auc: 0.5000 - val_prc: 0.0533

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comments, adding the images into the same data frame with the labels and creating 2d numpy arrays of images solved the issue. After waiting for more than 20 epochs, the model was showing values for tp, fp, tn, fn.
So all clear now!